# how to join 2 one to many entites jpql query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

product: id, name, @manyToOne() categoryId, @manyToOne() brandId

category: id,name, @oneToMany() products

brand: id,name, @oneToMany() products

i have entites like that. so i want to create a dto for product.

for example;

productDto: name,categoryName

so i can create query `@Query("Select dtoPath.productDto(p.name,c.name)  From Category c Inner Join c.products p")`

but i want to dto like;

- productDto: name,categoryName,brandName

how can i add join to query for brand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse single valued relations in the JPQL, and JPA will take care of the joins:

```
SELECT dtoPath.productDto(p.name, p.categoryId.name, p.brandId.name)
FROM Product p
WHERE ...
```

If you want all the products, just omit the `WHERE` clause. If you want all products in a certain category, try `WHERE p.categoryId=:category` (and pass the entire `Category` entity) or `WHERE p.categoryId.id=:categoryId` (and pass the category id only).

(Irrelevant suggestion, do not append `Id` to the name of the relation properties `Product.categoryId` and `Product.brandId`)